# This is no longer located in (Path). Verify the item's location and try again

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, file-location

The title says it all and I've never came across such an issue on Windows ever.

Am running Windows 8.1 Pro. I've downloaded a few Cartoon episodes recently and they are located in the **Downloads** folder.

Whenever am trying to **Move** it to my External Hard Disk, it throws me the below error.

[image: Could not find this item]

I tried renaming the folder. I tried to move the folder to the Desktop, but same issue. Clicking on Try Again does nothing but pops this back up.

Moving this folder from Downloads to Desktop works.

Comment: Which folder are you trying to move?  You will not be able to move the Downloads folder using File Explorer.

Comment: @Ramhound Was moving `The Flintstones` folder in Downloads but anyways, I figured it out. I'll just post and answer and will keep this question here. Fix was foolish ...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The issue was the External Hard Disk USB. Not sure if was not functioning well or loose but re-attaching it to the Hard Disk fixed the issue. Also, it's worth noting that I had started the Hard disk after a few months.

**How did I figure out the above?**

After it failed to Copy, I accessed the files on the External Hard Disk. The External drive was showing up in My Computer, and I was able to browse through all the folders but guess what? Most of the folders were not having the files they should be holding. Either they were empty or I couldn't open the files if they were in the list.

So I re-attached the USB cable and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of I copy the files from Linux operating system which filename allows character colon `:` but this is not a valid character in Windows filename.

I have to go back to Linux system to rename that files, then copy/paste again to windows, problem solved.

I just don't understand why Windows give misleading error message.